# Is there any issue in mongodb connection?

Tags: mongodb

I write this code and need to start localhost server every time to upload the image file but the image file is successfully uploaded to my mongodb atlas database and after deploy my project on netlify ,when I upload the image file and click on upload button  the file will not upload to my mongodb atlas database and after a refresh page not found error will appears on web page. Following is my code

This is js code

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const multer = require('multer');
const GridFsStorage = require('multer-gridfs-storage').GridFsStorage;
const Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
const app = express();

const mongoURI = 'mongodb+srv://tabish69122681:(Hide my password for privacy)@mycluster.94px1em.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
const conn = mongoose.createConnection(mongoURI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});

let gfs;
conn.once('open', () => {
    gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);
    gfs.collection('uploads');
});

const storage = new GridFsStorage({
    url: mongoURI,
    file: (req, file) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const fileInfo = {
                filename: file.originalname,
                bucketName: 'uploads'
            };
            resolve(fileInfo);
        });
    }
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
    res.status(201).json({ message: 'File uploaded successfully' });
});
app.get('/files', (req, res) => {
    gfs.files.find().toArray((err, files) => {
        if (!files || files.length === 0) {
            return res.status(404).json({
                err: 'No files exist'
            });
        }
        return res.json(files);
    });
});

app.get('/files/:filename', (req, res) => {
    gfs.files.findOne({ filename: req.params.filename }, (err, file) => {
        if (!file || file.length === 0) {
            return res.status(404).json({
                err: 'No file exists'
            });
        }
        return res.json(file);
    });
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5500;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`));
```

This is html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>File Upload</title>
    <script  src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file" id="imageInput" accept="image/*">
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you get any error? And also, are you using MongoDB Atlas?

Comment: yes I'm using mongodb atlas and no error shown except page not found after the  deployment

Comment: I do not understand the localhost issue and how it works on atlas but then after deploy does not work on atlas.   Sounds like a deployment issue?    Can the netlify deploy environment connect to the Atlas instance?